# Распределить текст в формулы

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Есть текст:

```
ВОЛНООБРАЗНЫЙ ИЗНОС, ШЛИФОВКА, УЧАСТОК, ЛОКОМОТИВЫ НОВОГО ПОКОЛЕНИЯ, ДИАГНАСТИЧЕСКИЙ КОМПЛЕКС, ГЛУБИНА ВОЛНЫ, АНАЛИЗ, РЕЛЬСОШЛИФОВАЛЬНЫЙ ПОЕЗД.
Цель проекта – исследование причин образования волнообразного износа рельсов от локомотивов нового поколения.
    В результате работы над дипломным проектом проведен анализ участка, выявлены причины образования волнообразного износа рельсов.
    Рассчитана стоимость устранения волнообразного износа рельсов рельсошлифовальным поездом и рельсошлифовальным станком. Произведено сравнение этих способов.
```

К тексту, в верхнем регистре, нужно добавить к каждому слову или словосочетанию "#610: ". Должно выглядеть так:

```
#610: ВОЛНООБРАЗНЫЙ ИЗНОС
#610: ШЛИФОВКА
#610: УЧАСТОК
```

А весь остальной текст определить в поле "#331: ". Например:

```
#331: Цель проекта – исследование причин образования волнообразного износа рельсов от локомотивов нового
```

Попыталась добавить в поле каждое слово или словосочетание:

```
if a.isupper():
    for i in a:
        print('#610: ' + i)
```

Но получилось вот что:

```
#610: В
#610: О
#610: Л
#610: Н
#610: О
#610: О
#610: Б
#610: Р
#610: А
#610: З
#610: Н
#610: Ы
#610: Й
#610:  
#610: И
#610: З
#610: Н
#610: О
#610: С
#610: ,
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить поле не к букве, а к слову. И как остальной текст определить в поле 331. Заранее благодарна за ответ

Comment: А если сначала разбить текст  (split) на слова или словосочетания?

Comment: @MBo, разбила текст, все получилось. Спасибо!!! А как остальной текст определить в поле 331?

Comment: Текст в верхнем регистре нужно парсить только из первого предложения?

Comment: @MaxU, да, верхний регистр будет только в первом предложении.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если текст в верхнем регистре нужно парсить только из первого предложения:

```
import re

# splitting text into two parts: first sentence and the rest
head, _, rest = text.partition('.')
# getting rid of leading '\n'
if rest[0] == '\n':
    rest = rest[1:]
# generating text in needed format 
res = ('\n'.join(f'#610: {x}' for x in re.split(r',\s*', head))
       + '\n#331: {}'.format(rest.replace('\n', ' ')))
```

результат:

```
#610: ВОЛНООБРАЗНЫЙ ИЗНОС
#610: ШЛИФОВКА
#610: УЧАСТОК
#610: ЛОКОМОТИВЫ НОВОГО ПОКОЛЕНИЯ
#610: ДИАГНАСТИЧЕСКИЙ КОМПЛЕКС
#610: ГЛУБИНА ВОЛНЫ
#610: АНАЛИЗ
#610: РЕЛЬСОШЛИФОВАЛЬНЫЙ ПОЕЗД
#331: Цель проекта  исследование причин образования волнообразного износа рельсов от локомотивов нового поколения.     В результате работы над дипломным проектом проведен анализ участка, выявлены причины образования волнообразного износа рельсов.     Рассчитана стоимость устранения волнообразного износа рельсов рельсошлифовальным поездом и рельсошлифовальным станком. Произведено сравнение этих способов.
```

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, если строка в верхнем регистре будет не первая, то как изменить Ваш вариант? Я попыталась rest[0] переделать, но выходит ошибка.

Comment: @Ireen1985, лучше наверное задать новый вопрос с соответствующим примером(ами) текста.